# Integer Values returned by a function in C

Tags: c, function, integer, output

I have a C program like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_int()
{
    int i;
    i++;
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
int main()
{
    print_int();
    print_int();
    return 0;
}
```

The output returned by this program is

```
1
2
```

I have a doubt regarding this output. Shouldn't this be two garbage values because the variable i is not initialized ?

Comment: It's undefined bahaviour. 1 can also be garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting undefined behavior.

Probably the variable `i` resides in the same physical memory location on each invocation, it happens to be cleared on startup, and nothing is writing garbage there so you're seeing those particular values. If you were to call some other function between the two calls to `print_int()`, results would very likely differ.

That's just "luck" of course, and this program is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The value of an uninitialized local non-static variable is *indeterminate*, using it while it's still uninitialized leads to *undefined behavior*. Sometimes it can *seem* to work, but it really doesn't.

However your case is easy to explain. The local variable `i` must occupy some memory location. It just happens to be that that memory location contained `0` when the function was first called. And the next time you call the function it will be in the same location. This behavior should not be counted on though, undefined behavior is still undefined behavior.